# youtube-dl forcing to add meta tags or adding custom post-processor

Tags: python, metadata, youtube-dl

I like to add some additional features in youtube-dl script such as adding album name forcefully by using extra options like --album "Album Name" in command line. It may require to modify FFmpegMetadataPP class in ffmpeg.py (https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/tree/master/youtube_dl/postprocessor).

Where can I find documentation of youtube-dl for adding additional command line options and parsing its values inside a function or class?

When I am using youtube-dl with --add-metadata album name is missing in downloaded audio files.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the github site you reference, and look at the [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) page.